# Adding to an ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Just for starters this is for school. Not looking for an answer but I'm lost when adding both the date and weight into an object and then adding that object into an arraylist.

```
public void addEntry(String d, int w) {
    Diet dietConstructor = new Diet();
    entries = new Entry(d, w);
    diet.add(entries);
}
```

This method is what is adding to an object and then into an arraylist.

I'm not sure if it is adding objects into an arraylist incorrectly or if when I am trying to print the values and it is just calling the last entered and printing that.
Below is where I am trying to print the values.

```
public void viewList()
{
    String output = "";

    weightDiff = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < diet.size(); i++)
    {
        weightLossOrGain = entries.getWeight();

        System.out.print("  " + diet.get(i) + "\t      ");
        System.out.print(diet.get(i) + "\t   ");

        System.out.print(weightDiff + "\n\n");

        weightLossOrGain -= entries.getWeight();
    }

    System.out.println("-------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("Net Weight Loss/Gain = " + weightLossOrGain + "\n");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------\n\n");

}
```

Comment: Not wanting to give too much away you should reconsider how you are removing manipulating weightLossOrGain inside your for loop.

Comment: Can you paste full your source code here, loop code for add entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what I understand from your question, you are re-using entries as an object to add the object to the ArrayList.

You are adding the object to the ArrayList correctly, there is no bug there.

You're not actually accessing the weight from the ArrayList, you're accessing the weight of the last object made which is why you are just getting the value of the last object.

I do not understand your end goal correctly here. But here is what you should modify in the viewList function:

```
weightLossOrGain -= diet.get(i).getWeight();
```

Comment: @m3m3th1n: to mark this as solved, please click the tick/check symbol adjacent to the answer that worked for you.